# How to keep a code running in VBA while a form window is open?

Tags: excel, forms, vba, button

In Excel VBA, I want to push a button, run some code, and while the code is running have a form window appear saying something like "Code is running, please wait until finished. Click stop button to terminate code."

But every time I .Show a form the code stops, waiting for the form window to be closed before continuing. Is there a way to force the code to continue to run while the form window is open?
Thanks!

Answered: Add (False) at the end of .Show or change the form's ShowModal property to False. Then add Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) just after fmRunning.Show(False). Or insert "DoEvents" instead of the Application.Wait
Thanks all!!

Comment: Show the form without making it modal `UserForm1.Show(False)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I do that the form appears blank and unresponsive. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: try putting a `DoEvents` after calling the userform.

Comment: Damn @Scott is fast. :)

Comment: I added DoEvents, I get the same problem except now the window doesn't close at the end of the code like it used to, but at least after the code is done the form populates with text (#trolledByCode). Here is how I have it:
Sub codename()
DoEvents
fmRunning.Show(False) 'I have also tried it without the false and 'instead with vbModeless and another time setting it's properties to 0.
...
...
fmRunning.Close
End Sub

Comment: Add the DoEvents **after** the form.show command. Also, this is beginning to be another question. If it is still not solved, I'd say it is time to ask a new question, since the original problem here has been answered.

Comment: I figured it out, I removed the DoEvents and instead added Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) just after fmRunning.Show(False). 
This forced the code pause long enough to let the form load completely with the text, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Also, 0=False=vbModeless, so use whichever you like. vbModeless is a constant equaling 0. It supposedly improves readability, but does nothing more.

Comment: Oh cool, glad you worked it out.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, you shouldn't post the answer in the question. Either accept an existing answer, or post it as your own answer and accept it (you can only accept your own answer after a day or so, if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: Oh, ok I'll do that going forward. Thanks Vacip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the userform to be modeless. This can be done two ways:

- either by selecting the userform and changing the ShowModal property to False
- or by opening the userform with setting the modal property to 0 (vbModeless)

```
Userform.Show vbModeless
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251540.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but when I do either of those the form appears blank and unresponsive. Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Using only `Userform.Show vbModeless` can cause blank form.
You should also use the command `Userform.Repaint`. This will refresh the info on the form. Example:

```
Userform.Show vbModeless
Userform.Caption = "Some text"   'change the Caption text
Userform.Repaint   'refresh changes
```

This way you should see the changes

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the form in the Project panel.
2. Change the **ShowModal** to **false**

this will keep your code running even the form is opned

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is advising the user to wait then you don't need an extra form.  Simply add a label to the form that say "Please wait...".  Set the label as hidden until the button is pressed then make it visible at the start of the code and hide it again when the code finishes.  You might need to insert DoEvents straight after the visible = True instruction as it might be overtaken by the main section of code.

`me.label1.visible = true/false`